# Damage to neighbor's utility in the easement on my property

Tags: easement, contractor

Had some landscaping company do work on my trees. They brought in a tractor machine that damaged a sewer clean out that is at grass level in the utility easement between my property & my neighbor. This clean out is for the neighbor's house but it's on my side of the property line. I told the neighbor and I've contacted the contractor twice about this. The contractor says he'll deal with it but he seems very slow to do anything. My concern is if the contractor flakes out am I going to be on the hook to deal with this? I'm also wondering about preventing the hassle in the future but not sure if it's worth it. Seems like something the neighbor should be doing but they don't seem interested/concerned.

Comment: Update: Contractor ignored my messages until I told him I'll pay if he agrees to giving me a discount on the next job. Suddenly he started responding. I had the damage fixed out of my pocket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your contractor is your agent

If your agent damages someone’s property, legally you damaged it. If you break it, you have to fix it. Your neighbour can sue either you or the contractor and they know where you live.